# Scala XML: create a node not using literals

Tags: xml, scala

How can I create a node in Scala without using literals?

What I need is to set the node tag name in runtime, for example:

```
var tag = "post"
var content = "234"
```

How can I get a node `<post>234</post>`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
scala> import xml._
import xml._

scala> def textElem(name: String, text: String) =  Elem(null, name, Null, TopScope, Text(text)) 
textElem: (name: String,text: String)scala.xml.Elem

scala> textElem("foo", "bar")                                                                   
res0: scala.xml.Elem = <foo>bar</foo>
```

Answer (score 24):

On Scala 2.8:

```
<xml>{content}</xml>.copy(label = tag)
```