# Making XML tags generic in Scala

Tags: xml, scala, tags

I am writing a function like this:

```
def contractXML[T](element:T):Elem = {
      element match {
        case element:Contract => <element> ABC </element>
    ......
```

How do I make the tag take in the element value from the parameter passed to contractXML function rather than just literally print just

```
<element>
```

?

Currently, it gives the error:

```
not found: value <
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you refer to with "tag"? If I take `<element> ABC </element>`, this is legal Scala code and compiles fine, so if you get `not found: value <`, you must be doing something different from what you pasted above...

Comment: I do not want it to take the string 'element' literally. I want it to take the value of the element and make an XML tag out of it.

Comment: You will to specify type `Contract` actually is. Does it convert to a string?

Comment: I think I got what I was looking for.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530907/scala-xml-create-a-node-not-using-literals) Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Okay, so [This was what I was looking for][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530907/scala-xml-create-a-node-not-using-literals