# Why does not the <{tag}></{tag}> scala.xml syntax work?

Tags: xml, scala, syntax

```
val tag="foo"

//works
val xml= <elem kind={tag}>some text</elem>

//does not work
val xml= <{tag}>some text</{tag}>
```

I want to create an xml element of a tag name that is not known in advance. How can I do this? Creating an element with the xml.Elem constructor is very complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
val tag = "foo"
val xml = <anything>some text</anything>.copy(label = tag)
```

as outlined by Daniel Sobral here [Scala XML: create a node not using literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530907/scala-xml-create-a-node-not-using-literals)

Comment: Awesome! This is really simple compared to creating an element with the constructor.